# How can I remove a chip from a controlled autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working with the Material-UI "Autocomplete" component to have multi-select capability.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9zlfz?file=/chipdemo.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const handleOnChange = ({ target }) => console.log(target.value);
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      value={state}
      onChange={(e, newval) => {
        console.log(newval);
        setState(prev => [...prev, newval[newval.length - 1]]);
      }}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Combo box"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
...
];
```

I'm attempting to utilize it as a controlled component, I'm able to add as many chips as I'd like from the list, however when it comes to removing them individually, I have two different cases

If the autocomplete has 1 chip (length of 0) and I click the x, I'm served with

> TypeError
> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

If the autocomplete has > 1 chip and I click the x, It will instead add the last chip over and over again.

Looking at the autocomplete API (https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) I dont see any "onClose" for the chips themselves, only for the popup with the options within.

Is there a specific prop I need to remove items from a controlled Autocomplete?

Thank you for any thoughts, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your code here, in your question body.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your onchange to this:

```
onChange={(e, newval) => {
        console.log(newval);
        setState(newval);
      }}
```